# How does SwipeyTabsSampleActivity did not generate a compilation error?

Tags: java, android

I was trying to make another sample from SwipeyTabsSampleActivity developed in [android-playground project](http://code.google.com/p/android-playground/)

Here is the sample code and my question is why i did not get a compilation error upon referencing of two variables "mViewPager" & "position" in method getTab->view.setOnClickListener

Here is the full sample source code. I tried the sample code first and it compiled and running well which I don't know how meanwhile when I was trying to customize the sample according to my needs. Everything went fine (compilation & running) except when I intended to set onClickListener and referencing these two variables, I got the following two compilation errors
1- Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field mViewPager
2- Cannot refer to a non-final variable position inside an inner class defined in a different method

I think that these two errors should have appear in the sample code as well not only my code but I dont know why?

```
/*
 * Copyright 2011 Peter Kuterna
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package net.peterkuterna.android.apps.swipeytabs;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SwipeyTabsSampleActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final String [] TITLES = {
        "CATEGORIES",
        "FEATURED",
        "TOP PAID",
        "TOP FREE",
        "TOP GROSSING",
        "TOP NEW PAID",
        "TOP NEW FREE",
        "TRENDING",
    };

    private SwipeyTabs mTabs;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_swipeytab);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mTabs = (SwipeyTabs) findViewById(R.id.swipeytabs);

        SwipeyTabsPagerAdapter adapter = new SwipeyTabsPagerAdapter(this,
                getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        mTabs.setAdapter(adapter);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(mTabs);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }

    private class SwipeyTabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
            SwipeyTabsAdapter {

        private final Context mContext;

        public SwipeyTabsPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);

            this.mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return SwipeyTabFragment.newInstance(TITLES[position]);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return TITLES.length;
        }

        public TextView getTab(final int position, SwipeyTabs root) {
            TextView view = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                    R.layout.swipey_tab_indicator, root, false);
            view.setText(TITLES[position]);
            view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
                }
            });

            return view;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getTab()` is an instance method of a non-static inner class of `SwipeyTabsSampleActivity`, so it has an implicit reference to its outer class instance, and has access to all the fields and methods of this instance, and thus to `mViewPager`. The `OnclickListener` is an anonymous inner class of the inner class of `SwipeyTabsSampleActivity`, and thus also has access to all the fields and methods of its two outer class instances.

If the inner class was static, it wouldn't compile. If `mViewPager` was a non-final local variable of the `getTab()` method, it wouldn't compile either.